# Backup Windows 2008 R2 Server to a ISO file

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server-2008, iso-image, xen

I want to virtualize a Windows 2008 R2 Server system for testing. At the moment the system in question is installed in a server and I want to make a copy of everything to an ISO file to then virtualize using Xen in Linux.

Is it possible? If so, how can I create this ISO from the original installation?

Comment: Any disk imaging tool worth its salt will do this, but the server will have to be OFFLINE to do it. Look at Norton Ghost, Acronis TrueImage or similar.

Comment: Are you sure you want an ISO file ? You can create an image of the serves disks with many tools, even if it is online, but they will create hard disk images (you can convert them later on). http://live.sysinternals.com/disk2vhd.exe is one of the free tools. You might want to check vmware converter too.